# Уникальный вывод множественного значения мета-поля WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap, foreach

Хочу сделать галерею в постах WordPress по следующему типу:

[image: Хочу такую галерею]

У меня есть в постах дополнительное поле, и так я вывожу массив с url картинок.

```
<?      
$gimgs = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-imgssrc');  
$imgcount = 0;
foreach ($gimgs as $gimg) {
  $imgcount++;
  if($imgcount >5) break; 
  echo $gimg;
}
?>
```

Однако, вывод крутой галереи предполагает вывод первых трех картинок в:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"><img src="imageurl"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"><img src="imageurl"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"><img src="imageurl"></div>
</div>
```

а вывод еще двух в

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"><img src="imageurl"</div>
  <div class="col-md-6"><img src="imageurl"</div>
</div>
```

А в последней колонке последней строки мне надо вывести еще и ссылку на полную галерею фотографий. Помогите пожалуйста, я новичок в php... как этот foreach заставить выводить первые три картинки так, а две вторые по-другому?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Счётчик вы создали, надо его использовать внутри цикла, вот и всё.

```
$gimgs    = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpcf-imgssrc' );
$imgcount = 0;
foreach ( $gimgs as $gimg ) {
    $imgcount ++;

    $imageurl = ''; // ... здесь вам надо вытащить url картинки из $gimg

    if ( 1 === $imgcount ) {
        ?>
        <div class="row">
        <?php
    }

    if ( ( $imgcount >= 1 ) && ( $imgcount <= 3 ) ) {
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-4"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( $imageurl ); ?>"></div>
        <?php
    }

    if ( 4 === $imgcount ) {
        ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <?php
    }

    if ( ( $imgcount >= 4 ) && ( $imgcount <= 5 ) ) {
        ?>
            <div class="col-md-6"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( $imageurl ); ?>"</div>
        <?php
    }

    if ( $imgcount >= 5 ) {
        ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        break;
    }
}
```